# UITableView's contentInset.top is 20 points larger than it should be in iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I have a `SearchViewController`, and as part of this `ViewController` I have a `UISearchController` (with a `SearchResultsController` called `SearchResultsTableViewController`). I notice that my `SearchResultsTableViewController`'s `UITableView` `contentInset.top` is 20 points more than it should be, despite it being fine on iOS8/9 and having `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` = true. If I perform a segue from this `ViewController` to another, then go back, I see that the `contentInset.top` increases another 20 points. Again, this does not occur on iOS8/9. Here are a [couple of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmVPH.jpg) showing this behavior.

Here is the code for the two relevant `ViewControllers`.

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    var searchController: UISearchController!
    var backBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
    var searchButtonTapped = false
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: SpringLabel!
    @IBOutlet var loadingIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchResultsVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultsTableViewController") as! SearchResultsTableViewController
        searchResultsVC.searchController = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsVC)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsVC
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Courses"
        searchController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .dark

        self.setSearchBarCaretColor(UIColor(red: 0.24, green: 0.34, blue: 0.19, alpha: 1.0))
        self.setSearchBarFontSize(17.0)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.backBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
        self.backgroundImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        self.titleLabel.alpha = 0
        self.titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        self.titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
        self.titleLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.titleLabel.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        self.loadingIndicatorView.layer.zPosition = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.perform(#selector(SearchViewController.showKeyboard), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)
        searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchController.searchBar)
    }

    func showKeyboard() {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func hideKeyboard() {
        self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.titleLabel.delay = 0.1
        self.titleLabel.animation = "zoomIn"
        self.titleLabel.duration = 0.6
        self.titleLabel.animate()

        let selectedRowIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if ((selectedRowIndexPath) != nil) {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRowIndexPath!, animated: true)
            self.transitionCoordinator?.notifyWhenInteractionEnds({ context in
                if (context.isCancelled) {
                    self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedRowIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func setSearchBarCaretColor(_ color : UIColor) {
        let view = searchController.searchBar.subviews[0]
        let subViewsArray = view.subviews
        for subView in subViewsArray {
            if subView.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                subView.tintColor = color
            }
        }
    }

    func setSearchBarFontSize(_ pointSize : CGFloat) {
        let view = searchController.searchBar.subviews[0]
        let subViewsArray = view.subviews
        for subView in subViewsArray {
            if subView.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                let textField = subView as! UITextField
                textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize)
            }
        }
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
//This doesn't animate for some reason, so don't use it.
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != .pad) { //Because the iPad (for some reason) doesn't ever show the Cancel button, so keep the back button.
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView()) }, completion: { Void in
                self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
            })
        }
    }


    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if (self.searchButtonTapped == false) {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.backBarButtonItem
            self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            self.searchButtonTapped = false
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.backBarButtonItem
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchButtonTapped = true
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Now here is SearchResultsTableViewController:

```
class SearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var resultsArray = [CourseResult]()
    var emptySearchResultsView : EmptySearchResultsView!

    var keyboardActive = false
    var keyboardHeight : CGFloat = 0.0

    var searchController : SearchViewController!
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Course")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

        self.emptySearchResultsView = EmptySearchResultsView.construct(self) as EmptySearchResultsView
        emptySearchResultsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.emptySearchResultsView.isHidden = true
        self.tableView.addSubview(emptySearchResultsView)

        query.whereKey("institution", equalTo: "College")
        query.limit = 20
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.registerKeyboardNotifications()
        let selectedRowIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if ((selectedRowIndexPath) != nil) {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRowIndexPath!, animated: true)
            self.transitionCoordinator?.notifyWhenInteractionEnds({ context in
                if (context.isCancelled) {
                    self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedRowIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.unregisterKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    var lastSearch = ""
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard searchController.isActive else { return }
        if (lastSearch == searchController.searchBar.text!) {
            return
        }
        self.lastSearch = searchController.searchBar.text!
        query.cancel()
        self.emptySearchResultsView.isHidden = true

        if (searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count == 0) {
            resultsArray.removeAll()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        if ((searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count)! > 0) {
            self.searchController.loadingIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            var searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
            searchString = searchString.lowercased()
            var searchStringArray = searchString.components(separatedBy: " ")
            searchStringArray = searchStringArray.filter { $0 != "" }
            //print(searchStringArray.description)
            query.whereKey("searchTerms", containsAllObjectsIn: searchStringArray)
            query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (results, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    self.resultsArray = []
                    let courseResultsArray = results! as [PFObject]
                    for result in courseResultsArray {
                        //removed all of this jargon.
                    }
                    self.searchController.loadingIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    if (self.resultsArray.count == 0) {
                        self.emptySearchResultsView.isHidden = false
                    } else {
                        self.emptySearchResultsView.isHidden = true
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    self.searchController.loadingIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        if (self.keyboardActive == true) {
            self.emptySearchResultsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: self.tableView.bounds.height - self.keyboardHeight - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
            self.emptySearchResultsView.setNeedsLayout()
        } else {
            self.emptySearchResultsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: self.tableView.bounds.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
            self.emptySearchResultsView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resultsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellContent: CourseResult = self.resultsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CourseResultTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CourseResultTableViewCell
        cell.backgroundView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.courseLabel.text = cellContent.courseCode + " - " + cellContent.courseName
        cell.universityLabel.text = cellContent.university
        cell.facultyLabel.text = cellContent.faculty

        cell.leftHandSideImageView.image = UIImage(named: cellContent.faculty)
        cell.leftHandSideImageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.leftHandSideImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        cell.leftHandSideImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        cell.leftHandSideImageView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let schedulesVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchedulesViewController") as! SchedulesViewController
        schedulesVC.selectedCourse = self.resultsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        self.searchController.show(schedulesVC, sender: tableView)
    }

    func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchResultsTableViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchResultsTableViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func unregisterKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != .phone) { //Because devices like iPads don't have they keyboards affect the error screen visibility much.
            return
        }
        if let keyboardFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { self.emptySearchResultsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: self.tableView.bounds.height - keyboardFrame.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
                self.emptySearchResultsView.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
            self.keyboardActive = true
            self.keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != .phone) {
            return
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { self.emptySearchResultsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: self.tableView.bounds.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
            self.emptySearchResultsView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        self.keyboardActive = false
    }

}
```

Each of these `ViewControllers` have their own representation in the storyboard.

Does anyone have an idea why I see this behavior, which is only seen in iOS10? The issue occurs on a wide range of devices from what I have tested.

Note: Just ignore any string parsing code related to the results or any other related code. I removed some of this stuff to try to make the code a little more coherent, along with json parsing code, etc

The only solution that has worked for me (which is not ideal) is to check if the device is running iOS10 and to dynamically adjust the `contentInset.top` based on the height of the status bar and `navigationBar`. Obviously I had to turn off `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` to do this.

Comment: I had this problem too. Did you find a way to fix this? I also notice that everytime the search results controller is appear, it call `updateSearchResults`. That makes the space on top of tableView large each time and the whole tableView is reloaded. This didn't happen in iOS < 10. What happened with Apple, this should appear only in beta version of iOS :|

Comment: The only way I could fix it was by manually setting the uitableview's contentInset based on the height of status bar, height of nav bar, etc for devices running ios10 or greater. That solution has worked great, but it shouldn't have to be done.